# USQL logging, debugging and troubleshooting

Tags: azure, debugging, logging, u-sql

Is there any way to log and debug issues in an USQL Script?
Here I am not talking about the UDO.

In more detail I am extracting data from multiple data lake files and don't know which one file failed. I am wondering if there is a way to log from the USQL script (not UDO).

Thank you,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I log something in USQL UDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46800248/how-can-i-log-something-in-usql-udo)

Comment: I modified my question. I am talking about logging from USQL script not the UDO.

Answer (score 1):

How are you reading the files? Built-in Extractors? With File Sets? What type of failure do you get?

You can write a logging UDO to write out information. Or you can look into the Vertex Execution View to see which vertex failed and see how much data the vertex read. Sometimes, if you get one file per vertex you can use that information to find out which file failed.

Also please file/upvote a feature request at http://aka.ms/adlfeedback that the error message will include the file on which the extraction failed.

Comment: Built-in extractors. Most of the failures are relating to the source azure file has special characters or new line character found in the text of a column value.